# JS: How do include functions argument into a large chunk of string

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I want a function to return argument for conditional statement that I use very often, but I can not get how to fit the **functions argument** inside the string. Here is the function:

```
function conditionForLinks(textNum, linkNum){
    return "${typeof(contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl+textNum) !== 'undefined' && contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl+textNum && 
typeof(contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkText+linkNum) !== 'undefined' && contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkText+textNum}"
}
```

Comment: typeof(contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl+textNum) - what is this supposed to be? :P

Comment: it is demandware script , ds is an ecommerce platform

Comment: is contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl supposed to be a number?

Comment: it should be a string like the statement.

Comment: `function hi(name){ return "Hello " + name + "!" ; }`

Comment: what happens if you remove the "${" part from the return? Is that really needed? and also: i see that you are already using your arguments (like textNum) inside the return.. i don't understand..

Comment: @dandavis thanks it works

Comment: if some one marks the question negative, I will like to know why please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to have multiple arguments passed through a single variable? such as

```js
    function foo(i, j){
        
    }
    
    var bar="1,2";
    foo(bar);
```

if so try

```
var bar= {i:1, j:2};
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank You this works:

```
function conditionForLinks(textNum, linkNum){
            return "${typeof(contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl"+textNum+") !== 'undefined' && contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkUrl"+textNum+" && typeof(contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkText"+linkNum+") !== 'undefined' && contentAsset.custom.brandInfoLinkText"+textNum+"}"
        }
```